# nbf keeps updating every time I send a JWT (Replay)

Tags: php, jwt, session-cookies

This is the file that creates the jwt token : jwt.php

```
<?php
ini_set("display_error", 1);
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$iss = 'localhost';
$iat = time();
$exp = $iat + 3;
$nbf = $iat + 5;
$aud = "myusers";
$user_arr_data = array(
    "id" => '001',
    "name" => 'test name',
    "email" => 'test@test.com'
);

$payload_info = array(
    'iss' => $iss, // issuer of the database
    'iat' => $iat, // Time at which this token was issued
    'exp' => $exp, // Expiry
    'nbf' => $nbf, // Time interval for the validity of this token
    'aud' => $aud, // Audience (Valid Users)
    'data' => $user_arr_data, // Data

);

$secret_key = 'bGS6lzFqvvSQ8ALbOxatm7/Vk7mLQyzqaS34Q4oR1ew=';
$jwt = JWT::encode($payload_info, $secret_key);
$jwt = base64_encode($jwt);
$jti = base64_encode('12345abcd');
header('Authorization: Bearer ' . $jwt);

setcookie("token", $jwt, time() + 30, "/");
$_COOKIE['token'] = $jwt;
setcookie( 'jti' ,$jti, time() + 30, "/");
$_COOKIE['jti'] = $jti;
```

I'm using cookies to send this JWT to the decoder : decodejwt.php

```
<?php
ini_set("display_error", 1);
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "token_id");

use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

if (!isset($_COOKIE["token"])) {
    http_response_code(404);
    print_r($_COOKIE["token"]);
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 0, 'message' => "There was an Error"));
    exit;
} else {
    $token = base64_decode($_COOKIE["token"]);
    $jti = base64_decode($_COOKIE["jti"]);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `token_id` where `ID` = '".$jti."'";
// checking for if this user has the same token id saved in their DB.

    $resp = $db -> query($sql);
    if($resp->num_rows == 0){
        http_response_code(404);
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 0, 'message' => 'Token ID does not match'));
        exit;
        die;
    }
}
try {
    $secret_key = 'bGS6lzFqvvSQ8ALbOxatm7/Vk7mLQyzqaS34Q4oR1ew=';
    $decoded_data = JWT::decode($token, $secret_key, array('HS256'));
    http_response_code(200);
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'message' => 'we got the JWT token', 'user_data' => $decoded_data));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    http_response_code(404);
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 0, 'message' => $e->getMessage()));
    exit;
}
```

I then include these files in a dummy page to test this token expiration date and nbf: test.php

```
<?php

require_once('./jwt.php');

require_once( './decodejwt.php');

echo "hello";
```

The problem here is everytime I run test.php I see this error (If nbf is set to iat + non-zero number):

```
{"status":0,"message":"Cannot handle token prior to 2022-05-25T12:18:44+0530"}
```

After every reload this time increases. If nbf is set to iat + 0 it works fine. Can someone please help me with this. I need the concept of nbf so as to not allow replay of the same token.

Comment: From the error i think the iat or nbf or exp are loading strange data try to put a date time no simply time

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work.
`$iat = date('"Y-m-d H:i:s"');
$exp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+300 sec"));
$nbf = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+20 sec"));`

tried it out this way. Didn't work.

Comment: I've also tried the following formats :
`$iat = strtotime(date('c'));
$exp = strtotime(date("c", strtotime("+300 sec")));
$nbf = strtotime(date("c", strtotime("+20 sec")));`

This gives the same original error